# Change text in already existing text file with javascript

Tags: javascript, text-files, txt

I want to change the text in a .txt with just a few lines of code but have not been able to find anything that, to a 100%, fulfills my purpose.

This is how the situation looks like:

1. I have a .txt-file with the text "1"
2. I want to change the text in this file from "1" to "2" with Javascript.

This is how I imagine it to look like:

```
File myFile = "myTextDoc.txt";
myFile.text = "2";
```

I know this ain't the right way but I hope it can better picture how I want it to work.

Thanks

Edit: I know how to get the text from the -txt-file to a string and change it but I don't know and send it back to the .txt-file.

Comment: Where is this code to be run?

Comment: Read the file into a string. Parse the string with `parseInt()`. Add 1 to the result. Write the result back to the file.

Comment: If you don't know how to read and write files from JavaScript, there are tutorials that will help you.

Comment: He meant does it run on the client or server?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it will be run on a server

Comment: @Barmar I've searched a lot and I just find overcomplicated scripts that don't work for me anyways. Therefore I wonder if there is any simple way to do it.